# Is there a way Gitlab CI could work with another repository?

Tags: gitlab, continuous-integration, gitlab-ci

I know there are a lot of subject on Gitlab CI but after some time digging, I decided to ask for help.

Here is my situation :

To stay simple ,I have got 3 repositories in the same gitlab group: one with the datas, one with the tools and the last one for the results of computed datas computed with the tools. Why split them ? For security issues, someone accessing tools may not have access to datas or results. HOWEVER, i would like the gitlab CI to run on every changes on datas, to import the tools (basically cloning the repo), use them and commit/push on the results project.

Configuration context:

- I have got my own managed gitlab server and runner on different VMs.
- My runner is registered in the group level so my 3 repos can access it.
- I blocked HTTP and HTTPS cloning meaning i can only clone with SSH.

My gitlab-ci.yml file in the datas repository:

```
job:
  script:
    - eval $(ssh-agent -s)
    - echo "$SSH_PRIVATE_KEY" | tr -d '\r' | ssh-add -
    - echo "HOST *" > ~/.ssh/config
    - echo "StrictHostKeyChecking no" > ~/.ssh/config
    - git config --global user.email "test@gmail.com"
    - git config --global user.name "gitlabrunner"
    - ssh git@GitlabServer #works well
    - cd ..
    - git clone git@thisproject #works well
    - git clone git@anotherproject #doesn't work
```

Problem:
When trying to clone the project (datas) where the gitlab CI is running, everything works fine, the project is clone and I can work on it.
When trying to clone another projet (tools or results) an error is popping : "remote: The project you were looking for could not be found or you don't have permission to view it".
Of course i have permission and it exists because I can clone it on my own terminal.

Could you help me figure out where is problem is landing and how could i achieve it ?

Many thanks

Comment: `echo "SSH_PRIVATE_KEY"` -> `echo "$SSH_PRIVATE_KEY"`

Comment: Oh indeed, typing mistake

Comment: `Of course i have permission` How do you know then? The message tells you what it tells you. Is SSH_PRIVATE_KEY set? `echo "HOST *" > ~/.ssh/known_hosts` Are you sure that is valid syntax for known_hosts file? `echo "StrictHostKeyChecking no" > ~/.ssh/config` There has to be a section header before option. Are you sure you did not mix the commands?

Comment: You damn right, i made some typing recopy mistake (because i work on another machine that the stackoverflow one), it's indeed `echo "HOST *" > ~/.ssh/config` but it doesn't solve my error. I know i have the permission since i can easily clone these repos (tools and results on my terminale) with that same ssh key or even access it on the gitlab web interface but it looks like gitlab runner can't. And yes the command `echo $SSH_PRIVATE_KEY` give me the good key since i get it from the gitlab CI variables.